# deleting StorageFile in windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I want to capture images say every 10 sec. For this I will be using Timer class which will run following peices of code:

```
 async private void captureImage()
    {
        capturePreview.Source = captureManager;
        await captureManager.StartPreviewAsync();

        ImageEncodingProperties imgFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();


        // create storage file in local app storage
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
            "TestPhoto.jpg",
            CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);


        // take photo
        await captureManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imgFormat, file);

        // Get photo as a BitmapImage
        BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path));

        // imagePreivew is a <Image> object defined in XAML
        imagePreivew.Source = bmpImage;


        await captureManager.StopPreviewAsync();    
        //send file to server
        sendHttpReq();

         await file.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete); 


    }
```

Currently I am calling above function on button click,

I want to delete the file once image is transferred as I will be sending it to web server. However I dont see imagePreivew getting updated on button click whereas when I dont delete file I see imagePreivew changing everytime I press button. Also I tried with CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting but still faced same issue. Creating new file everytime timer executes task would waste lot of memory. How do I delete file???

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your are deleting the image before it has been loaded (the Bitmap is loaded asynchronously).

To solve that just replace,

```cs
    // Get photo as a BitmapImage
    BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path));
```

by

```cs
    using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
        {
            BitmapImage bmpImage = new BitmapImage();
            await bmpImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
        }
```

Like this you will await that the image load is finished before deleting it.

Also you should be awaiting  `sendHttpReq();` because otherwise the image will also be deleted before you send the request to the server.

One other thing that you might want to correct is that possibly there could be  a second call of captureImage while the previous capture is not finished. To fix that you could either use a IsStillCapturing flag and just return if it is still capturing or use an [AsyncLock](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266988.aspx) to prevent two CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync at the same time.

Comment: One suggestion: put the secondary operations like sendHttpReq and DeleteAsync into another async function that you can call but not await on in captureImage. That way you can return from captureImage and let the other stuff run in parallel.

Comment: @KraigBrockschmidt-MSFT Actually captureImage is not even returning a Task so it is executed aasynchronously so it will "return" as soon a the first await is done so that don't really matter.